# JavaScript and CSS

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, requirejs

I found a "partial" solution on the Internet, but if I use that "solution", my store don´t works:

[image]

If I use that, this is the result:

*Home JS page*

*Store*

[image]

Like you can see, if it makes me choose between JS and CSS in only one place, in my store or in my Home Page. If I delete that line in my .htaccess file, the store is fine, but this is my Home Page:

I don´t know how make it work... Any help, please?

If you need some more info, please tell it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling versioning of static files as you've done by running sql query, you also have to deploy static content. Just to be safe rename you pub/static folder.

Now run following commands ;

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

chmod 777 -R var pub generated
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: It doesn´t work... I renamed static folder, and Magento says that pub/generated doesn´t exist.

Answer (score 0):

No need to update .htaccess

Just run the following commends

1. rm -rf ./pub/static/*
2. rm -rf ./var/view_preprocessed/*
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
5. php bin/magento cache:clean
6. php bin/magento cache:flush